# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope

Tags: android, ksoap2

Hai am Calling the webservice in my android application am using android version(r-18).but i got error in Soap serilization.am trying  the ksoap2 version(2.5.4,2.4,2.6.4,2.5.8).

Error Message;

```
05-07 02:20:26.920: W/dalvikvm(4852): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d888)
05-07 02:20:26.920: E/AndroidRuntime(4852): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-07 02:20:26.920: E/AndroidRuntime(4852): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope
05-07 02:20:26.920: E/AndroidRuntime(4852):     at com.android.StringBuilderActivity.<init>(StringBuilderActivity.java:31)
05-07 02:20:26.920: E/AndroidRuntime(4852):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
05-07 02:20:26.920: E/AndroidRuntime(4852):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1429)
05-07 02:20:26.920: E/AndroidRuntime(4852):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
05-07 02:20:26.920: E/AndroidRuntime(4852):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2582)
05-07 02:20:26.920: E/AndroidRuntime(4852):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2684)
05-07 02:20:26.920: E/AndroidRuntime(4852):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:126)
05-07 02:20:26.920: E/AndroidRuntime(4852):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2038)
05-07 02:20:26.920: E/AndroidRuntime(4852):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-07 02:20:26.920: E/AndroidRuntime(4852):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-07 02:20:26.920: E/AndroidRuntime(4852):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4632)
05-07 02:20:26.920: E/AndroidRuntime(4852):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-07 02:20:26.920: E/AndroidRuntime(4852):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-07 02:20:26.920: E/AndroidRuntime(4852):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:871)
05-07 02:20:26.920: E/AndroidRuntime(4852):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
05-07 02:20:26.920: E/AndroidRuntime(4852):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: ya i add i mention the version also in my question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change your library file names to "/libs" and check it.

Comment: hi.. its libs in my case :( but still finding this issue

Comment: @Aada: yes, some times we face the issue with updated eclipse versions even add jars in /libs folder. for resolve this issue you should add libs(jars) in java build path.from eclipse use right click on project -> properties -> select java build path (from left side panel) -> click on add jars(button) -> select project -> add jars -> click ok

Answer (score 4):

I have encountered the same issue .... go to Build Path >> Configure Build Path >> Order and export >> Select KSOAP2 lib . (I am assuming that u have add KSOAP2 Jar)

Answer (score 4):

Starting with ADT version 17 I believe, Android dependencies are automatically gathered from the `libs` folder in the root of your project. Try moving your SOAP library to that folder and cleaning your project.

Comment: by default we dnt have libs folder right ? So u want to create a lib folder and move jar in that folder.

Comment: Correct, you need to create the folder. Naming is important. Make sure it is `libs`.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you forgot to add the external JAR file.

try right clicking you project folder, going to build path and adding the JAR file to the project.

Comment: i added the jar file and  i mention the version also in my question

Answer (score 0):

Create a directory named `libs` in your project

Now copy & paste your .jar file into `libs` directory.

Right click on project build path to add library

select from libs directory & ok

Run -> Success 
Enjoy

Comment: Try to be more clear in you answer it will help others to understand your answer better.