# Java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError on emulator

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror

First of all I know a number of similar question with their answers exist here on Stack Overflow. Yet I am asking this as none of them have worked. I have added the external jars to "libs" folder.

Moreover the funny thing is that classes from commons.math-2.2.jar seem to work properly. The problem is only when I try to use classes from jsci-wavelet.jar
I have checked the build path n number of times. There seems to be no problem there.
I only have one package in my source code.

By the way I am using Android 2.2 emulator. (Though even checked it for Android 4.0.3 but to no avail.)

Sorry But stack exchange does not allow me to upload images

Comment: Did you add the missing jar to the Android project settings?

Comment: use http://tinypic.com/ and http://pastebin.com/ for your pastes.

Comment: doesn't that `jsci-wavelet.jar` have any other `jsci-...` dependencies that also need to be resolved?

Comment: if your sdk is not updated to 16.0 above better to use libs instead lib.

Comment: Checkout this link : http://stackoverflow.com/a/10477702/1037078

Comment: @YusufX Yes, it would be silly of me not to.

Comment: @rekaszeru No, it worked on a shorter version of the app.

Comment: I used libs. It's showing Android dependencies.

Comment: @MohitSharma I had already done that. Quite a number of times for that.

Comment: @KazekageGaara as a new user I am not allowed to link to images :(

Comment: check java build path>order and export. If your library is not checked then check it, and if you using the latest ADT(>16) then, there are some changes made to the order of libs and sources in new ADT versions.

Comment: @mak_just4anything Yes I have done that. I think I'll check rekaszeru's comment about jsci-dependency as I had used a different class in the smaller app.

Comment: Thanks a lot @rekaszeru. You were write. Checked the problematic class' source. It was importing other classes.

Comment: That's great! :) now you should answer your question describing how you fixed it, and accept it: this way others will be able to learn from it too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK this one was not so much of a head ache.
As suggested by [@rekaszeru](https://stackoverflow.com/users/506879/rekaszeru) I checked if there were any dependencies of `jsci-wavelet.jar`
I checked its source. It said:

```
import JSci.maths.wavelet.*;
import JSci.maths.*;
```

i.e it required the classes in JSci.maths package too.
So I added the `fsci-core.jar` to the dependencies and viola, it works perfectly.