# NoClassDefFoundError: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject

Tags: android, ksoap2

.Problem is that project was not made by me.I have added this project and checked that all the necessary library file exist or not.Required KSOP2 Jar file is already in libs folder.And as the logcat suggest it is related with soapobject. Searched a lot before asking this question but none of the solution worked for me.May be this time I have explained properly.Please ignore some English language related error.

```
07-02 11:41:42.369: E/AndroidRuntime(3633): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-02 11:41:42.369: E/AndroidRuntime(3633): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
07-02 11:41:42.369: E/AndroidRuntime(3633):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2695)
07-02 11:41:42.369: E/AndroidRuntime(3633):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3122)
07-02 11:41:42.369: E/AndroidRuntime(3633):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:11942)
07-02 11:41:42.369: E/AndroidRuntime(3633):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-02 11:41:42.369: E/AndroidRuntime(3633):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-02 11:41:42.369: E/AndroidRuntime(3633):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
07-02 11:41:42.369: E/AndroidRuntime(3633):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4028)
07-02 11:41:42.369: E/AndroidRuntime(3633):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-02 11:41:42.369: E/AndroidRuntime(3633):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
07-02 11:41:42.369: E/AndroidRuntime(3633):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:844)
07-02 11:41:42.369: E/AndroidRuntime(3633):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
07-02 11:41:42.369: E/AndroidRuntime(3633):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-02 11:41:42.369: E/AndroidRuntime(3633): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
07-02 11:41:42.369: E/AndroidRuntime(3633):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-02 11:41:42.369: E/AndroidRuntime(3633):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
07-02 11:41:42.369: E/AndroidRuntime(3633):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2690)
07-02 11:41:42.369: E/AndroidRuntime(3633):     ... 11 more
07-02 11:41:42.369: E/AndroidRuntime(3633): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject
07-02 11:41:42.369: E/AndroidRuntime(3633):     at com.test.android.Dashboardlogin.validatelogin(Dashboardlogin.java:83)
07-02 11:41:42.369: E/AndroidRuntime(3633):     at com.test.android.Dashboardlogin.onBtnClicked(Dashboardlogin.java:62)
07-02 11:41:42.369: E/AndroidRuntime(3633):     ... 14 more
```

Comment: Search before asking..  
http://stackoverflow.com/a/17106357/2194831

Comment: Hi,already seen that Example but doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Paste your `external jar` in `libs` directory and then give `path` from your libs directory `right click` on `project-->properties-->java build path-->add external jar's`-->select your libs directory

Comment: Done as you have told but nothing changed,same error.Problem is that project was not made by me.I have added this project and checked that all the necessary library file exist or not.Required KSOP2 Jar file is already in libs folder.And as the logcat suggest it is related with soapobject. Searched a lot before asking this question but none of the solution worked for me.May be this time I have explained properly.Please ignore some English language related error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added

```
ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

to be put under **/libs folder** so Eclipse ADT automatically adds your jars to the buildpath of your application.

And also you can

1. Go to "Properties" of the project.
2. Select "Java Build Path"
3. Add External jars.

Comment: ksoap2-android-assembly-2.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar is in the /libs folder when i added the project.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10477632/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-ksoap2-serialization-soapserializationenvelo

Answer (score 0):

```
 1)Go to "Properties" of the project.
 2)Select "Java Build Path"
 3)Add External jars.
```

And Also add that external file to **libs** folder.
   **libs->New->file->Advanced**..and add jar file to it.